# Sharepoint Profiles vanish after move-spuser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

We're migrating users from one domain to another, using

```
Move-SPUser -IgnoreSID -Identity $user -NewAlias $User2 -Verbose
```

Although no errors are reported, custom profile properties are not transferred.

Is this expected? What can be done?

Comment: is it one domain to other domain within same UPA?

Comment: Yes, there is only one. Actually, adjusting the import filters to reflect the new OU fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, adjusting the import filters to reflect the new OU fixed this. –  George Winters Apr 27 at 20:23